# iBatis Silent Failure to Map Columns

Tags: java, sql, ibatis

When I am mapping a POJO with iBatis such as below:

```
Person {
    String firstName
    String lastName;
}
```

To the query:

```
select firstName, last_name from Person
```

I am finding that Person.firstName is populated correctly whereas Person.lastName is null - this happens silently. I can introduce a ResultMap to fix the null issue (by translating last_name -> lastName), but I would like iBatis to throw an error when attempting to map rather than doing the best it can silently...

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't iBatis automatically maps SQL convention names to Java convention names? I mean, should not iBatis automatically try to map column `last_name` to Java field `lastName`? Just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several issues.

### I'm Blind!

The class `Person {     String firstName     String lastName; }` 
provides exactly 0 visible elements to iBatis because iBatis neither extends Person nor shares the package of Person.  Consider the following:

```
public class Person
{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(final String newValue)
    {
        firstName = newValue;
    }

    public void setLastName(final String newValue)
    {
        lastName = newValue;
    }
}
```

### Seperate and Not Equal

last_name is in no way the same as lastName.
Consider using a result map like the following:

```
<resultMap id="theIdOfThisMap"
           class="Person">
    <result property="firstName" column="firstName"/>
    <result property="lastName" column="last_name"/>
</resultMap>

<select id="searchForEntities"
        resultMap="theIdOfThisMap">
    select
        firstName,
        last_name
    from
        PERSON
</select>
```

Comment: Hi DwB - I already have the ResultMap working and the Person class was provided for illustration of parameter names, not visibility so my apologies for the confusion. My concern is that iBatis does not seem to warn when it is unable to map a database column to an equivalent class property, e.g. in absence of the ResultMap- do you know how I can force it to warn/error as this will be useful to find errors quickly during development?

Comment: iBatis claims that it will map any column that matches a property in the class.  last_name and lastName do not match therefore they are not covered by the statement "will map any column that matches".  I dont know a way to get ibatis to identify non-matching columns from a query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [aliasing with AS](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-as.html):

```
SELECT firstName, last_name AS lastName
FROM   Person
```